# Remove Document in Sub-collection Firebase | Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I build App that has a list of notifications and tries to allow users to delete a specific document in the subcollection with the codes below. But it removes all documents in the subcollection and then the app crashed!!!

```
....

       itemView.setOnClickListener {
           getDocumentId()

        }

    }

            
    private fun getDocumentId() {

        db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.email!!)
            .collection("notification").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Listen Failed", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (snapshot != null) {
                    val documents = snapshot.documents
                    delete(documents[position].id)
                    }
                }
            }

    private fun delete(docNotificationID: String) {
        db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.email!!)
            .collection("notification").document(docNotificationID)
            .delete()
    }




}
```

...

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact document you want to delete. Please also explains why are you using addSnapshotListener in order to only delete a document?

Comment: I used "addSnapshotListener" to get the document ID.

Answer (score 0):

That should not delete all the documents. I would recommend adding success and failure listeners to prevents any misbehaviour. Can you try this?

```
private fun delete(docNotificationID: string: String) {
  Log.d("TAG", docNotificationID)
  db.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.email!!)
        .collection("notifications")
        .document(docNotificationID)
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!") }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w("TAG", "Error deleting document", e) }
}
```

Things to notice will be the logged notification ID and the out from either success or failure listener.

Also why are you fetching the complete collection in the `getDocumentId()`? I'd recommend storing the document ID into the list item when you initially fetch the data so you have access to it on click events or so.

Comment: Nothing changes the app still crashing!

Comment: @MarwanTalal please share the logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
    Process: com.qalamp.eqalamschool, PID: 12506
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.qalamp.eqalamschool.cloudMessaging.NotificationsAdapter$NotificationsItem.getDocumentId$lambda-1(NotificationsAdapter.kt:55)
    at com.qalamp.eqalamschool.cloudMessaging.NotificationsAdapter$NotificationsItem.lambda$vNXlPl5asSXhSQAmF9DARy_I1m0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.qalamp.eqalamschool.cloudMessaging.-$$Lambda$NotificationsAdapter$NotificationsItem$vNXlPl5asSXhSQAmF9DARy_I1m0.onEvent(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2$Query(Query.java:1133)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.-$$Lambda$Query$JWhMgzcsIac1Z-exZj1pTDRisJg.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0$AsyncEventListener(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$AsyncEventListener$DNkggu2LY54oguDvcp-QtRg6Sfg.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:6)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```